# How to replace Nested For loops in Apex Code?

Tags: apex, trigger

As I am new to salesforce I am struggeling to optimise the code. My code requires the nested for loop to be replaced in order to perform better

Heres my code that needs correction-

```
List<PermissionSetAssignment> psaList = new List<PermissionSetAssignment>();       
        for (User u : newUsers) {
            User oldObj=(User)oldMapObj.get(u.Id);
                if(userPermissions.size()>0 && userPermissions[0].Permission_sets__c!=null ||userPermissions[0].Permission_set_groups__c!=null){
                    if(oldObj!= null || u.Tag__c != oldObj.Tag__c){
                        for(PermissionSet lst: permSets)
                        {
                                PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment();
                                psa.AssigneeId = u.id;
                                psa.PermissionSetId = lst.id;
                                psaList.add(psa);
                        }
                        for(PermissionSetGroup lst: permSetGroup)
                        {
                            PermissionSetAssignment psga = new PermissionSetAssignment();
                            psga.AssigneeId = u.id;
                            psga.PermissionSetGroupId = lst.id;
                            psaList.add(psga);
                        }
                    
                     }
                }
        }
```

Comment: If the requirement is to assign each user to a set of permission sets and a set of permission set groups then the nested loops are needed and the performance is largely a consequence of the requirement. Using e.g. maps to avoid nested loops is a technique were you are trying to hook up the current item in a loop to a pre-existing set of records usually via an Id.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.. I think you are right

Comment: I've posted this as an answer so you can accept it and avoid distracting other people thinking this is an unanswered question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the requirement is to assign each user to a set of permission sets and a set of permission set groups then the nested loops are needed and the performance is largely a consequence of the requirement. Using e.g. maps to avoid nested loops is a technique were you are trying to hook up the current item in a loop to a pre-existing set of records usually via an Id.